# vb.net How to make a DropDownList with readonly appearance

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, readonly

I am developing desktop application using vb.net and vs2008.

I have a DropDownList that I don't want it interact with use when the info is locked.

But if I disable it, it is greyed out and the text is not easy to read.

Is there any way to make radiobutton like readonly textbox?

I want text of the DropDownList looks black and itself is not clickable.

[image]

The above shows a disabled DropDownList with greyed out text and a readonly textbox

Comment: Your first example is a DropDownList, not a radio button.  Which one are you looking for?  As far as making it look like a read-only textbox, you might have to use CSS.

Comment: Can I use CSS for desktop application?????

Comment: sorry for the confusing image, but I want the readonly look for both radiobutton and dropdownlist.

Comment: The standard windows behaviour when a control is disabled is for it to be greyed (or grayed) out, changing this behaviour for your application should not be encouraged as it will be confusing for your users. If you have a piece of text that is static you should use a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently encountered a similar issue.  My solution was to remove all other values of the DropDownList except the one that is selected.  This will keep the text as black as opposed to grey.  Users will be able see the existing value and click it but will not be able to change it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Enable="false"`

Place it within your `<asp:DropDownList>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use CSS in a desktop app. When you disable the dropdownlist by setting Disabled=true; or Enabled=false (whatever the case is), you can also change the Font properties to make it easier to read. You can set other properties such as Border, BorderStyle, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the control enabled. In the GOTFOCUS event, use SENDKEYS to send a {tab} to the form. the user will not be able to change it! By the way, workt  for ALL controls, that a user can focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Or ComboBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0 Then e.Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
    For i = 0 To ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If Not ComboBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Items(i) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```